# Label curve segments

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry, computational-geometry

I want to label every part of the following curve like in the figure. The label origin should start from the middle of the curve segment see the graphic. I think that something is not quite right in my logic. Could you assist where is the error in my code? I think that the code and the figure explain itself.

Thanks for your time and help!

```
    CGFloat radius = self.height / 3.2f; // radius of the curve
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.width / 2.f, self.height / 2.f); //center of the curve
    UIBezierPath* circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:degreesToRadian(270.f) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(269.999f) clockwise:YES]; // go around like the clock

    CGFloat strokeStart = 0.f;
    // Add the parts of the curve to the view
    for (int i = 0; i < segmentValues.count; i++) {
        NSNumber *value = [segmentValues objectAtIndex:i];
        CGFloat strokeEnd = [value floatValue] / kPercentHundred;

        CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        circle.path          = circlePath.CGPath;
        circle.lineCap       = kCALineCapButt;
        circle.fillColor     = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        circle.strokeColor   = [[colors objectAtIndex:i] CGColor];
        circle.lineWidth     = kWidhtLine;
        circle.zPosition     = 1.f;
        circle.strokeStart   = strokeStart;
        circle.strokeEnd     = strokeStart + strokeEnd;
        [self.layer addSublayer:circle];

        UIView *example = [[UIView alloc] init];
        example.backgroundColor = kColorRed;
        example.size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        // middle = "(circle.strokeStart + circle.strokeEnd) / 2.f"
        // * convert percent to degree
        CGFloat angle = (circle.strokeStart + circle.strokeEnd) / 2.f * 360.f;
        // determine the point and add the right offset
        example.origin = CGPointMake(cosf(angle) * radius + center.x, sinf(angle) * radius + center.y);
        [self addSubview:example];

        strokeStart = circle.strokeEnd;
    }
```

What I get see the figure.
[image: What I got]

What I expect in concept is something similar to the following figure.

[image]

Comment: Your angle calculation doesn't look right. strokeStart and strokeEnd are supposed to be values from 0 to 1. So, if you want to convert those to angles, you should be using (strokeStart+strokeEnd)/2 * 2 * M_PI, which simplifies to (strokeStart+strokeEnd) * M_PI 

(Angles are expressed in radians, ranging from 0 to 2 pi, not 0 to 360.)

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you very much. Also I added this  "degreesToRadian(270.f)" to angle and now it works. Could you move your comment to your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two key issues:

1. You calculate the angle via:

   ```
   CGFloat angle = (circle.strokeStart + circle.strokeEnd) / 2.f * 360.f;
   ```

   You then proceed to use that for the `cos` and `sin` functions. Those expect radian values, though, so you have to convert this to radians before you use it in those functions. Thus, yielding:

   ```
   CGFloat angle = degreesToRadian((circle.strokeStart + circle.strokeEnd) / 2.f * 360.f);
   ```

   (BTW, I don't know if you prefer `degreesToRadian` or `DEGREES_TO_RADIANS`, but you should probably use one or the other.)

   Or, more simply, you can convert to radians directly:

   ```
   CGFloat angle = (circle.strokeStart + circle.strokeEnd) / 2.f * M_PI * 2.0;
   ```
2. You have rotated the circle 90 degrees (presumably so that it would start a "12 o'clock" rather than "3 o'clock"). Well, if you rotate the circle, then you have to rotate `angle` when you calculate where to put your `example` view, as well:

   ```
   example.center = CGPointMake(cosf(angle - M_PI_2) * radius + center.x, sinf(angle - M_PI_2) * radius + center.y);
   ```

This yields:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your goal is. You say you want to create labels, but what you create in your code is generic UIView objects.

Then you are setting a property "origin" on the view, but UIView does not have an origin as far as I know. It has a frame, which has an origin component, but not an origin property. I'm guessing that the code you posted is not actual, running code.

Do you want the labels to be centered on top of the circle? If so, you should both set the text alignment to NSTextAlignmentCenter, and set the center property of the views rather than the frame.origin.

I have a working sample project on github that creates an analog clock and puts labels for the hours around it. You can look at the code for an idea of how to do it:

[**Analog clock sample project**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/ClockAnimation)

(The project also shows how to use the new spring physics UIView animation method.)

Comment: I copied the code from xcode so it is running. I want to place labels like you see in the last figure. Thanks for your project and answer, I am going to check it now.

Comment: So what is the origin property? How is that legal code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention.  I've written a Category over UIView and I implemented some useful methods like setting origin, size, x, y, .. etc

Comment: Important information. You should use the center property instead, and make sure to set your label to be centered. Why does your code add blank UIViews, but your image shows red blocks and text labels? Again, the image you show doesn't match the code.

Answer (score -1):

hmm it i a little late for me ;)

I think you have to use UIView::setCenter this will solve you problem. Then the center of the view is on your circle.

Edit: And it is easier to manipulate the position.

Comment: Maybe my explanation about the problem is wrong but this solution is far far from my question, but thanks to spend time with my question.